# How to delete website, store and storeviews other than from the admin panel (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to delete websites, stores and store views form a Magento 1.9 store. I tried it from the admin panel on a staging environment which is a clone of the live site. It didn't go very well. After loading for a while it served a 500 error. And it still is. See below.

**Is there another (better?) way to do this instead of doing it from the admin panel since this approach is very risky (losing connection, timeouts, PHP time-limits etc).**

I looked in [Magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) but unfortunately, it doesn't have such an option.

`AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 645 and defined in /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php:453\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(645): Mage_Core_Model_Store->setWebsite(NULL)\n#1 /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()\n#2 /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')\n#3 /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)\n#4 /home/kubusk/domains/qaz35-lthbnm6754.nl/staging/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')\n#5 {main}\n  th...\n'`